# Visual Basic 6: error 91 and 13 when executing a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, vb6, connection

I'm new to Visual Basic 6  and I'm trying to execute an stored procedure and get the result into a text field variable.

The code below shows this error: error 91 
"Object variable or With block variable not set" runtime error

```
Dim auxInfo As rdoResultset
Dim Cone As ADODB.Connection
    SQL = "EXEC  [mybase].[dbo].[myStoredProcedure] '" & var1 & "', '" & var2 & "','" & var3 & "'"
    Set auxInfo = Cone.Execute(SQL)
    myTextField.Text = Trim(auxInfo("fistColumn"))
    auxInfo.Close
```

And if I change the following:

```
Set auxInfo = Cone.Execute(SQL)
```

into

```
   Set auxInfo = UAN.OpenResultset(SQL, rdOpenDynamic, rdConcurValues, 0)
'with UAN I call the funcion that connects to my database. The connection works, I've tested it.
```

I get a new error: error 13 type mismatch

Could please tell what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is that your full code? (Please don't change anything when postiong code and askign for help) If it is, then you're missing the `Set Cone = New ADODB.Connection`

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but I would suggest that conn or even cn is a better variable name than cone for a connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, You've not actually set `Cone` to anything.
You're missing the `Set Cone = New ADODB.Connection`.